Error messages show when they are not suppose to show
I am starting to learn and I am coding a frontend mentor challenge which is almost done. It is an age calculator and I want the error messages to show when the input is not a number or when the number exceeds the days of the month etc, by using toggle to the class which hides and show the error. However the error messages are shown when the opposite happens, I mean when the input is a correct number between the days of the month, or the 12 months etc. I tried changing the logic to the opposite but that way the errors are always showing so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks!


const dayInput = document.getElementById("day-input");
const monthInput = document.getElementById("month-input");
const yearInput = document.getElementById("year-input");
const yearResult = document.getElementById("year-result");
const monthResult = document.getElementById("month-result");
const dayResult = document.getElementById("day-result");
const dayError = document.getElementById("day-error");
const monthError = document.getElementById("month-error");
const yearError = document.getElementById("year-error");

const calculateDifferences = () => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  const currentDay = currentDate.getDate();

  const day = parseInt(dayInput.value);
  const month = parseInt(monthInput.value);
  const year = parseInt(yearInput.value);

  if (!isNaN(day) && !isNaN(month) && !isNaN(year)) {
    let yearDiff = currentYear - year;
    let monthDiff = currentMonth - month;
    let dayDiff = currentDay - day;

    if (dayDiff < 0) {
      monthDiff--;
      dayDiff += new Date(currentYear, currentMonth - 1, 0).getDate();
    }

    if (monthDiff < 0) {
      yearDiff--;
      monthDiff += 12;
    }

    yearResult.innerText = yearDiff;
    monthResult.innerText = monthDiff;
    dayResult.innerText = dayDiff;
  } else {
    yearResult.innerText = "--";
    monthResult.innerText = "--";
    dayResult.innerText = "--";
  }
};

const validateInputs = () => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

  const day = parseInt(dayInput.value);
  const month = parseInt(monthInput.value);
  const year = parseInt(yearInput.value);

  const isDayValid = !isNaN(day) && day >= 1 && day <= 31;
  const isMonthValid = !isNaN(month) && month >= 1 && month <= 12;
  const isYearValid = !isNaN(year) && year <= currentYear;

  dayError.classList.toggle("active", !isDayValid);
  monthError.classList.toggle("active", !isMonthValid);
  yearError.classList.toggle("active", !isYearValid);

  if (isDayValid) {
    dayError.classList.remove("active");
  }
  if (isMonthValid) {
    monthError.classList.remove("active");
  }
  if (isYearValid) {
    yearError.classList.remove("active");
  }
};

const ageCalc = () => {
  validateInputs();
  calculateDifferences();
};

dayInput.addEventListener("input", ageCalc);
monthInput.addEventListener("input", ageCalc);
yearInput.addEventListener("input", ageCalc);

ageCalc();
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

:root {
  /* ### Primary */

  --Purple: hsl(259, 100%, 65%);
  --Light-red: hsl(0, 100%, 67%);

  /* ### Neutral */

  --White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --Off-white: hsl(0, 0%, 94%);
  --Light-grey: hsl(0, 0%, 86%);
  --Smokey-grey: hsl(0, 1%, 44%);
  --Off-black: hsl(0, 0%, 8%);
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--Off-white);
  padding: 70px 10px;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  background-color: var(--White);
  border-radius: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
}

.data-container {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: var(--Smokey-grey);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: var(--Light-red);
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input {
  width: 23vw;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 5vw;
  border: 1px solid var(--Smokey-grey);
}

.divission {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

hr {
  top: calc(50% - 50px / 2);
  left: calc(50% - 50px / 2);
}

.icon {
  background-color: var(--Purple);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px / 2);
  left: calc(50% - 50px / 2);
}

.results-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 12vw;
  font-weight: 800;
}

span {
  color: var(--Purple);
}

.active {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.date-error-color {
  color: var(--Light-red);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
  main {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--Off-white);
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px 40px;
    background-color: var(--White);
    border-radius: 20px 20px 30% 20px;
    width: 50vw;
    height: fit-content;
  }

  .data-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
  }

  .block {
    width: 15vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: fit-content;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: var(--Smokey-grey);
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: var(--Light-red);
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  input {
    width: 10vw;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 2vw;
    border: 1px solid var(--Smokey-grey);
  }

  .divission {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

  hr {
    top: calc(50% - 50px / 2);
    left: calc(50% - 50px / 2);
  }

  .icon {
    background-color: var(--Purple);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 50px / 2);
    left: 100%;
  }

  .results-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: 800;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hanken+Grotesk:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Josefin+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..700;1,100..700&family=Manrope:wght@200..800&family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Age calculator app</title>
 
</head>
<body>

  <main>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="upper-info">
        <div class="data-container">
          <div class="day block">
            <h1>Day</h1>
            <input id="day-input" type="text" placeholder="DD"></input>
            <h2 id="day-error" class="error active">Must be a valid day</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="month block">
            <h1>Month</h1>
            <input id="month-input" type="text" placeholder="MM"></input>
            <h2 id="month-error" class="error active">Must be a valid month</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="year block">
            <h1>Year</h1>
            <input id="year-input" type="text" placeholder="YYYY"></input>
            <h2 id="year-error" class="error active">Must be a valid year</h2>
          </div>
          
          
      </div>
        <div class="divission">
          <hr>
          <svg class="icon"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="46" height="44" viewBox="0 0 46 44"><g fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="2"><path d="M1 22.019C8.333 21.686 23 25.616 23 44M23 44V0M45 22.019C37.667 21.686 23 25.616 23 44"/></g></svg>
        </div>
        
     
      </div>
      <div class="results-div">
        <div class="years-result"><span id="year-result" ></span> years</div>
        <div class="months-result"><span  id="month-result"></span> months</div>
        <div class="days-result"><span  id="day-result"></span> days</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- <div class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
      Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>. -->
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




Please create a Stack Snippet and add the HTML so we can try your code.

You don't need to do both dayError.classList.toggle() and if (isDayValid)...

validateInput() should return an indication of whether the inputs were all valid. Then you can skip calling calculateDifferences() when there are invalid inputs, and you don't need to check validity when calculating.

You are right @Barmar, I removed "isDayValid" and now it is working. I made the changes to validaInput() to return the data. Thanks!
